# Problem with configuration in .NET,problem with read a json file(I'm using the latest version of Mobile devopment framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, maui

When I'm trying to add the JSON file via.AddJsonFile(), it throws a:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was '/data/user/0/com.companyname.rakeshproj/files/appsettings.json'.'

Also, I tried to set the base path, but it didn't help, It can be supposed with the Android system security.
Screenshots:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nec8J.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttNLg.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6EEl.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcp4d.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/biTNJ.png
```

```
namespace RakeshProj;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Extensions.JsonRead(@"C:\Users\Matsenko\source\repos\TestJson\TestJson\appsettings.json");
        /////////////////Problem
        IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        //.AddJsonFile("appsettings`.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
        /////////////////Problem
        //Menu menu_settings = config.GetSection("ShellContentNames").Get<Menu>();


        ShellContent[][] ShellContentName= 
        {
        new ShellContent[3]
        {
            ShellContent1_1,ShellContent2_1,ShellContent3_1
        },
        new ShellContent[13]
        {
                 ShellContent1_2,ShellContent2_2,ShellContent3_2,
                 ShellContent4_2,ShellContent5_2,ShellContent6_2,
                 ShellContent7_2,ShellContent8_2,ShellContent9_2,
                 ShellContent10_2,ShellContent11_2,ShellContent12_2,ShellContent13_2    
        }
        };
        string[][] ShellContentTitle =
        {
        new string[3]
        {
            "Test1_1","Test2_1","Test3_1"
        },
        new string[13]
        {
                 "Test1_2","Test2_2","Test3_2",
                 "Test4_2","Test5_2","Test6_2",
                 "Test7_2","Test8_2","Test9_2",
                 "Test10_2","Test11_2","Test12_2","Test13_2"
        }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < ShellContentName.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < ShellContentName[i].Length; j++)
            {
                ShellContentName[i][j].Title = ShellContentTitle[i][j];
                SemanticScreenReader.Announce(ShellContentName[i][j].Title);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does the file exist in the first place? Was it published along with the binary?

Comment: Yep, I think the problem is in the Maui  and android security, cause the exact code works in the console app but doesn't in Maui @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Are you aware of MAUI assets? If that file `appsettings.json` is part of your solution and you want it on the Android device during deployment, make it a MAUI asset in the build options of the file.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks, but can you send me some docs on how to do it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/single-project mentions the build actions. Will need to see which part of the documentation shows using it, it is basically `using (var inputStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(assetName))`

Comment: Some (not quite up to date code sample) is in https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-to-Preview-13 under "Raw Assets"

Comment: @MartinHonnen Not working

Comment: In my understanding, for it "to work", you need to ensure the build action as a MAUI asset is set but then, to have that file also in e.g. `/data/user/0/com.companyname.rakeshproj/files/appsettings.json`, your app's code needs to copy it there by using e.g. `using (var inputStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("appsettings.json"))` to read it from the app package and then copying the file with File IO to your wanted location. I don't know, however, whether that is the intended or working way for configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using it as the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration method won't work for the time being, it's being considered, but at the earliest for .NET 7: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4408

If you want to read a file from your app bundle, do the following:

1. Add the file to your Resources\Raw folder
2. Make sure the build action is set to `MauiAsset`
3. Read the file contents like below and do with it as you please :)

```cs
using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("foo.json");
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

// For example deserialize JSON here.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how can I check the build action set to MauiAsset @GeraldVersluis

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoXlo.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppx1g.png

Comment: https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/

Comment: Please check this, whar's wrong with it? @GeraldVersluis

Comment: You shouldn't need the "RakeshProj.", just "appsettings.json". To see the Build Action; right-click on the json file and click Properties. In that screen you should see a column Build Action

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNff1.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CFgu.png

Comment: Please,check also this @GeraldVersluis